# malformed config.xml error when updating code in phonegap

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new to phonegap. i am using phonegap build. I created all files according to the format and uploaded the file .i successfully created the apk. Then i make changes in files but when i tried to update the code it show the error malformed config.xml. So below i am showing the code of config.xml file i think error is in that file. So please help me to find what is the error?
`enter code here`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget id="com.phonegap.hybridapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name>Hybrid App</name>

    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author  email="nidhinjohny777@gmail.com">
        Nidhin johny
    </author>

    <!-- Define the main entry-point to the application -->
    <content src="index.html" />

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->

    <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="14" />
<!-- Core/Common Preferences -->


<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/> 

<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/> 

<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape"/>

<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false"/>

<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff0000ff"/>


<!--iOS Preferences-->

<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"/> 

<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>

<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>

<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>

<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="false"/>

<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true"/>

<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>

<preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>

<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>

<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>

<preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="fast"/>


<!--Android Preferences-->

<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/> 

<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/>

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="mySplash"/>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>

<preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true"/>

<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>

<preference name="LoadingPageDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>

<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>

<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>

<preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE"/>

<preference name="SetFullscreen" value="false"/>

<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
    <!-- Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app. -->
    <!-- <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="cli-6.0.0" /> -->

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Define app icon and splashscreen for each platform. -->
    <icon src="logo.png" />
    <platform name="android">
     <icon src = "www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" 
      gap:platform = "android" gap:qualifier = "ldpi" />

   <icon src = "www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" 
      gap:platform = "android" gap:qualifier = "mdpi" />

   <icon src = "www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" 
      gap:platform = "android" gap:qualifier = "hdpi" />

   <icon src = "www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" 
      gap:platform = "android" gap:qualifier = "xhdpi" />

   <icon src = "www/res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" 
      gap:platform = "android" gap:qualifier = "xxhdpi" />

  <icon src = "www/res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" 
      gap:platform = "android" gap:qualifier = "xxxhdpi" />

      <splash src="www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"    density="hdpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"     density="ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"    density="mdpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"    density="xhdpi" />

   </platform>
    <platform name="ios">

   <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "57" height = "57" />
   <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "72" height = "72" />
   <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon-2x.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "114" height = "114" />
   <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "144" height = "144" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"     platform="ios" width="768"  height="1024" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"  platform="ios" width="1536"  height="2048" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"               platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"     platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png"  platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
         <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png"  platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
          <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png"  platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
   </platform>
     <platform name="windows">
<icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" gap:platform = "windows" gap:qualifier = ""/>
   <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "57" height = "57" />
   <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "72" height = "72" />

    <access origin="*" />


    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be syntax error in your config.xml.

In your config.xml, you have opened tag for windows platform using `<platform name="windows">` but you have not close the platform tag for windows before opening an other platform tag for Android.

Icon source for windows platform should be corrected as follows in config.xml,

```
<platform name="windows">
    <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" gap:platform = "windows" gap:qualifier = ""/>
    <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "57" height = "57" />
    <icon src = "www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform = "ios" width = "72" height = "72" />
</platform>
```